# Ayuda con redux-thunks y axios, problema muy raro

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, redux

tengo un problema que no he podido resolver en mucho rato.

Tengo este código en mis actions

```
import { axiosClientWithToken } from '../../helpers/auth-helper';

export const ACTIONS = {
    GET_MEDIAS_LOADING: 'GET_MEDIAS_LOADING',
    GET_MEDIAS_SUCCESS: 'GET_MEDIAS_SUCCESS',
    GET_MEDIAS_ERROR: 'GET_MEDIAS_ERROR',
};

const getMediasLoading = () => ({
        type: ACTIONS.GET_MEDIAS_LOADING,
    });

const getMediasSuccess = (payload) => ({
        type: ACTIONS.GET_MEDIAS_SUCCESS,
        payload,
    });

const getMediasError = (payload) => ({
        type: ACTIONS.GET_MEDIAS_ERROR,
        payload,
    });

export const getMediasThunk = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {
        dispatch(getMediasLoading());
        try {
            const res = await axiosClientWithToken.get('/media/get');
            if (res.status === 200) {
                dispatch(getMediasSuccess(res.data));
            }
        } catch (error) {
            return error.response
                ? dispatch(getMediasError(error.response.data.message))
                : dispatch(getMediasError(error.message));
        }
};
```

el problema surge cuando hago el `dispatch(getMediasSuccess(res.data));` en las demas peticiones funciona super bien, pero en esta al momento de hacer el dispatch de la acción que setea los datos en el state por alguna razón me los esta cambiando.

Los datos originalmente llegan así  *(Fíjense en los media_type)*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al hacer el dispatch me los cambia a estos  *(Fíjense en los media_type, los cambio todos a video)*
:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es algo muy extraño que me este cambiando parte de la información, a que se puede deber esto ?

Si pongo un console.log al res.data junto al dispatch

```
console.log(res.data);
dispatch(getMediasSuccess(res.data));
```

El console me muestra mal la información, pero si le saco el dispatch me la muestra correctamente.

Por lo tanto el problema debe estar en axios o en redux-thunk.

A Alguien le ha pasado? saben como solucionarlo? de antemano muchisimas gracias.

Comment: como tienes los reducers?

Comment: Hola Isaac, dudo mucho que sean los reducers, ya que el error se produce antes de llegar a esa parte, pero te dejo una imagen de los reducers y una del axiosClient

https://i.imgur.com/SbLMHkT.png
https://i.imgur.com/dddFDan.png


Mis saludos